# MySQLI Insert not working not inserting blocked IP

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, insert

I have this code to insert new attempts to login so when people fail 7 times they get blocked. The problem is when trying to insert while IP is not listed on DB it just does not insert and I cannot understand why. Here is the code:

```
    session_start();
    $blocked = mysqli_query($db, "
SELECT * FROM `blocked` WHERE `ip` = '" . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] . "' LIMIT 1");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($blocked)==0){
    $insert = mysqli_query($db, "
INSERT INTO `blocked` VALUES ('', '" . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] . "', '1')");
    }
```

I get error

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

Comment: `$database != $db` Not only are vars case sensitive but they are sensitive to being totally different.

Comment: Sorry I forgot it but edited it and now both are $db, same problem

Comment: Look at the error and what it is telling you.  Parameter 1 of mysqli_query is `$db`.  So `$db` is null, not what *mysqli_query()* is expecting.  Since you don't show how `$db` is sourced, we can't really help you.

Comment: Also, when posting your `$db = mysqli_connect();` code, DO NOT give away your database credentials

Comment: @MonkeyZeus way to take the fun out of it...

Comment: @Devon If I didn't say anything now then surely someone would harp on novato upon posting such info

Comment: Always explicitly list the columns when you use `insert`.

Answer (score 0):

if `$db` was defined somewhere else, it might not be available.

There are ways to get variables to move around in different scopes, otherwise just connect again at the top of this script
`$db = connect(...)`